# pull remote branch without merge

Tags: git, git-push, git-pull

I've created a branch `b1` and I made some changes on it and I push it to the remote repository:

```
git branch b1
git checkout b1
git add newfile.txt
git commit -m "adding a new file"
git push origin b1
```

On an other machine which is connected to the remote repository, I tried to pull the branch without merge it with master:

```
$git branch
*master
$git pull origin b1
remote: Counting objects: 4, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
From sl*******02:/opt/git/projet1
 * branch            b1    -> FETCH_HEAD
Updating fca3b48..1d96ceb
Fast-forward
 newfile.txt |    1 +
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 newfile.txt

$git branch
*master
```

what I expected:

```
$git branch
*master
b1
```

Comment: It seems you have missed one step to checkout new branch before pushing your code?

Comment: `git branch` lists local branches, since you've never checked out `b1` it only resides in the remote, use `git branch -a` to list this as well. In order to get it as a local branch, check it out with `git checkout b1`, this will create a local branch out of the remote branch and set up upstream mapping between them.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen this is what I'm getting when I checkout b1 `error: pathspec 'b1' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

Comment: Try `git fetch` without parameters first, or `git fetch origin`

Comment: You can use `git cherry-pick` with `-n` option, thou that does pull only specific commits :)

Answer (score 55):

You are actually asking two questions:

- in the title - how to pull without merge (I came here for this question, originally;)
- in the description - how to check out a branch without merging in to master

### Pull remote branch without merge

```
# Assuming you are on wanted branch (b1) already

git pull --rebase
```

No `merge`, just `rebase`.

### Check out remote branch (from origin)

```
git fetch 
git checkout b1
```

No merge to `master`, new branch `b1` is created.

Comment: This was definitely the most useful answer for me. Doing a pull through a rebase in a single command is super convenient.

Answer (score 51):

You can use `git fetch origin b1` to only fetch remote branch without merge.

See : https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch

Basically `git pull` is a shortcut to `git fetch && git merge`

Merge execute because you was on master branch, and not your local b1 branch.

Answer (score 8):

You want to checkout the remote branch with

```
git checkout b1
```

if you are on a git version < 1.6.6 the way to do that is instead

```
git checkout -b b1 origin/b1
```

Comment: how could I checkout a branch if this one still not exist?

Comment: @Carole it defaults from the only remote available you already fetched

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: @Carole you first need to do git fetch, this fetches all the remote branches, and you can see them with git branch -a , when doing git checkout b1 you switch to the origin/b1 branch

Answer (score 4):

It also possible before committing

with the following commands

```
git stash
git pull
git stash apply
```

Comment: Please explain your answer a little more, because I want something like stash pop on some feature A branch, but changes in feature B branch is already committed...
So how to get the stash from branch feature B.

Answer (score 1):

```
git remote update origin —prune
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Commands are easier to read if formatted as code. Code only answers can generally be improved by adding some explanation of how and why they work and in the case of commands what expected output would look like if it was successful, or how to interpret the results of the command if applicable.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way:

steps:

- checkout to different branch
- git stash
- deleted the local branch in which was having merge error/conflict
- did git fetch all
- git checkout <branch_name in which you were getting merge error
  before>
- git pull origin

commands:

ex:

- > error branch name: Error-branch
- > other branch name: Other-branch
- `git checkout Other-branch`
- `git stash`
- `git branch -d Error-branch` (if doesn't work then use below)
- `git branch -D Error-branch` (if you have merge conflict)
- `git fetch all`
- `git checkout Error-branch`
- `git pull origin`

I hope this will solve your problem